# How to create a map in a loop in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am creating a 2d map and want to start by pre-filling it with empty values.

I know the following will not work in Elixir, but this is what I am trying to do.

```
def empty_map(size_x, size_y) do
  map = %{}

  for x <- 1..size_x do
    for y <- 1..size_y do
      map = Map.put(map, {x, y}, " ")
    end
  end
end
```

Then I will be drawing shapes onto that map like

```
def create_room(map, {from_x, from_y}, {width, height}) do
  for x in from_x..(from_x + width) do
    for y in from_x..(from_x + width) do
      if # first line, or last line, or first col, or last col
        map = Map.replace(map, x, y, '#')
      else
        map = Map.replace(map, x, y, '.')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried doing it as a 2D array, but I think flat map with coordinate touples as keys will be easier to work with.

I know I am supposed to use recursions, but I don't really have a good idea of how to do it elegantly and this scenario keeps coming up and I haven't seen a simple/universal way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two nested `Enum.reduce/3` here, passing the map as the accumulator, instead of writing recursive functions yourself:

```
defmodule A do
  def empty_map(size_x, size_y) do
    Enum.reduce(1..size_x, %{}, fn x, acc ->
      Enum.reduce(1..size_y, acc, fn y, acc ->
        Map.put(acc, {x, y}, " ")
      end)
    end)
  end
end

IO.inspect A.empty_map(3, 4)
```

Output:

```
%{{1, 1} => " ", {1, 2} => " ", {1, 3} => " ", {1, 4} => " ", {2, 1} => " ",
  {2, 2} => " ", {2, 3} => " ", {2, 4} => " ", {3, 1} => " ", {3, 2} => " ",
  {3, 3} => " ", {3, 4} => " "}
```

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks! Btw is there a way to get rid of the parentheses in the `end)` bit?

Comment: Yes, you can replace both the `reduce(` with `reduce` and `end)` with `end`. I prefer writing them out when the arguments are long but they're optional.

Answer (score 5):

One line using Comprehensions:

```
    for x <- 1..10, y <- 1..10, into: %{}, do: {{x, y}, " "}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to create a list tuples with comprehensions and convert it into a map.

```
iex(18)> defmodule Room do
...(18)>   def empty_map(size_x, size_y) do
...(18)>     for x <- 1..size_x, y <- 1..size_y do
...(18)>       {{x,y}, " "}
...(18)>     end
...(18)>     |> Enum.into(%{})
...(18)>   end
...(18)>
...(18)>   def create_room(map, {from_x, from_y}, {width, height}) do
...(18)>     last_x = from_x + width
...(18)>     last_y = from_y + height
...(18)>     for x <- from_x..last_x, y <- from_y..last_y do
...(18)>       if x == from_x or x == last_x or y == from_y or y == last_y,
...(18)>         do: {{x, y}, "#"}, else: {{x, y}, "."}
...(18)>     end
...(18)>     |> Enum.into(map)
...(18)>   end
...(18)> end
warning: redefining module Room (current version defined in memory)
  iex:18

{:module, Room,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 10, 244, 66, 69, 65, 77, 69, 120, 68, 99, 0, 0, 1, 10,
   131, 104, 2, 100, 0, 14, 101, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 95, 100, 111, 99, 115,
   95, 118, 49, 108, 0, 0, 0, 4, 104, 2, ...>>, {:create_room, 3}}


iex(19)> Room.empty_map(3,4) |> Room.create_room({1,2}, {3,3})
%{{1, 1} => " ", {1, 2} => "#", {1, 3} => "#", {1, 4} => "#", {1, 5} => "#",
  {2, 1} => " ", {2, 2} => "#", {2, 3} => ".", {2, 4} => ".", {2, 5} => "#",
  {3, 1} => " ", {3, 2} => "#", {3, 3} => ".", {3, 4} => ".", {3, 5} => "#",
  {4, 2} => "#", {4, 3} => "#", {4, 4} => "#", {4, 5} => "#"}
iex(20)>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to create my own solution, that would do the above in a manner that is understandable but still as concise as possible (I'm just a beginner myself).

```
  def create_room(left_bound, right_bound, lower_bound, upper_bound) do
    for x <- left_bound..right_bound,
        y <- lower_bound..upper_bound,
        into: %{}
    do
      draw_tile(x, y, border?(x, y, left_bound, right_bound, lower_bound, upper_bound));
    end
  end

  def border?(x, y, left_bound, right_bound, lower_bound, upper_bound) do
    x in [left_bound, right_bound] ||
    y in [lower_bound, upper_bound]
  end

  def draw_tile(x, y, _is_border = true) do
    {{x,y}, "#"}
  end

  def draw_tile(x, y, _is_border = false) do
    {{x,y}, "."}
  end
```

First of all, since a `Range` is inclusive (i.e. 1..4 is [1,2,3,4] and not [1,2,3]), I use actual bounds instead of width and height parameters. This makes it more clear to me what I have to do with the code.

Next, I make a simple comprehension, as shown in the answer of @AA., basically looping over all possible combinations of x and y.

If you return a two-element tuple within the body of that loop, then the first element of the tuple will be the key and the second will be the value inserted into the map.

Within the body, I use `draw_tile`, a function which takes coordinates and a boolean indicating whether the tile is a border-tile or not.

Finally, the function `border?` just checks if either `x` or `y` are equal to `left_bound` or `right_bound` and `lower_bound` or `upper_bound` respectively.

In Elixir, although `if` statements exist, it is more idiomatic to use pattern matching in a function, as I did with `draw_tile`.

Also, I think (personal opinion, not sure if this is reflected in the Elixir Community as a whole), nesting should be avoided as much as possible.

Edit:
You will also find a lot of information on syntax in the Elixir docs.

For example, see [Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) or [Kernel.in/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#in/2)